# how to check if a Windows.Form is empty(without controls) but not null?

Tags: c#

I have a function which returns an instance of Windows Form

```
public Form getForm(string Node)
{
    Form obj = new Form();

    obj = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(Node);
    return obj;
}
```

I am Calling this function as:

```
Form requestedForm = new Form(); 
requestedForm = getForm(system);
if ((requestedForm != null) && (requestedForm.Text!=""))
// to check if the Form is not empty.
{
    openform(requestedForm);
}        
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("No form Found");
}
```

In some cases I get `requestedForm.Text=""` even if the form  is not blank so how do I check this?

Comment: This code looks suspicious...

Comment: The form might not be blank but `.Text` of a form returns the text in the title bar thingy

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Do you really need Activator.CreateInstance? Are you just trying to make a new instance of a form, or is there a reason for the attempted complexity?

Comment: @Epickip ok thanks , might be that but would you suggest how to check that the form is not blank ? i used Form.Text because that was the only way i figured out to check.

Comment: I'm unsure of the syntax but maybe you can do something like `requestedForm.items.contains.count == 0`? Also, may I ask why you want to check this? Most of the time these forms are populated when they're created so this check is kind of strange.. If you're simply trying to error handle have you considered using a `try ... catch` statement?

Comment: @HockeyJ yes i do need to use Activator because my formname come from the database .

Comment: What do you mean by blank, no controls? Then it would be `form.Controls.Count > 0`

Comment: @capn JacK, i Encountered a situation when it gave me a blank Windows Form so i need to check whether the form is empty or not . i will try your suggestion

Comment: is a blank window one without any controls?

Comment: @Mong Zhu yes ,  A form without Controls .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public Form getForm(string Node)
{
    Form obj = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(Node);
    return obj;
}
```

Call this as:

```
Form requestedForm = getForm(system);
if ((requestedForm != null) && (requestedForm.Controls.Count > 0))
{//Form is not empty
    openform(requestedForm);
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("No form Found");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Activator.CreateInstance(String, String);](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d133hta4.aspx)

Try this

```
public static Form obj = null;

public Form getForm(string nmspace, string node) {
    if(obj == null){
        obj = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(nmspace, node);
    } 
    return obj;
}

void main () {
    Form requestedForm = getForm("form namespace", "form name");
    if (requestedForm != null) {
        openform(requestedForm);
    }        
    else {
        MessageBox.Show("No form Found");
    }   
}
```